# CMake generated makefile does not expand all `make` variables

Tags: cmake, makefile

I have a projects that consists of modules that are built separately. Some modules use `make` only, others use `cmake`.

The top project has a makefile, which is used to trigger the build of the submodules. The makefile at the top defines `make` variables for pathes to libs, includes, and binaries. The submodules then use these variables.

My problem is that I cannot pass all these `make` variables to the projects that use `cmake`.

For the include directory, this work-around in `CMakeLists.txt` works:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/$(INCLUDE_DIR)")
```

The string is passed as is all the way to the generated makefile, and is then expanded by `make` upon building. The leading slash is needed. Without it, the content of `INCLUDE_DIR` gets prefixed by the `cmake` project root (it is then considered a relative path).

This solution does not work for linking:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/$(LIB_DIR)")
```

The link command that I see upon building has the literal string `-L/$(LIB_DIR)`. Removing the leading slash gives a warning about relative paths, and the link command has still the unexpanded `$LIB_DIR`.

- How do I make sure that the expansion works for the `make` variable `LIB_DIR` passed though `cmake` to the generated makefile? Since it is `make` that runs the linker (I think?) I don't see why it wouldn't expand.
- Is there another, less ugly solution, solution for fixing it for `INCLUDE_DIR` as well?

A backup solution is to let the top makefile define `CMAKE` variables. It should work fine, and is probably what I'll do if I can't make it work otherwise. But it would be nice to just define these variables once and make everything else take them into account.

Comment: I would make these CMake variables using `$ENV{VAR}`

Comment: I mean `set (INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{INCLUDE_DIR})`

Comment: This worked! Make it an answer and you'll get the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an environment variable to set a CMake variable. For example:

```
set (INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{INCLUDE_DIR})
```

then use the CMake variable like other CMake variables:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${INCLUDE_DIR})
```

If you want the variable to show up in cmake-gui or ccmake you can put it in the cache using the following:

```
set(INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{INCLUDE_DIR} CACHE PATH "An environment variable containing a path" FORCE)
```

for my projects I have wrapped the concept in a cmake function:

```
function( define_from_environment VariableName PackageName)
  if (NOT DEFINED ${VariableName})
    message( STATUS "${VariableName}=$ENV{${VariableName}}" )
    if (NOT "$ENV{${VariableName}}" STREQUAL "")
      set(${VariableName} $ENV{${VariableName}} CACHE PATH "Set the path variable ${VariableName} for ${PackageName}" FORCE)
    endif (NOT "$ENV{${VariableName}}" STREQUAL "")
  endif(NOT DEFINED ${VariableName})
endfunction( define_from_environment)
```

An example usage of this CMake function is

```
define_from_environment(GDCM_DIR GDCM)
```

which sets the CMake variable GDCM_DIR to a CMake cache variable if the environment variable GDCM_DIR is set.

Comment: For now I have gone the simplest way: `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{INCLUDE_DIR})`.